# HDInsight subscription not working - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

When i executing hive activity I got the error as  **No subscription found to host the HDInsight cluster. Cluster size requested: 4**
What weird is i'm already had the subscription !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message itself is misleading. Subscription here means ADF internal subscription, not yours.

It seems to me that the region you specified in on-demand HDI LS doesn't have enough cores to handle your request at that time.

You may either retry your pipeline (could be transient issue) or report an incident to Microsoft with runID (if consistently repro).

Comment: How to report this incident to Microsoft? Is there a protocol can i get ?

Comment: https://portal.azure.com/
There is a question mark icon on the top right corner -> Help+Support.

Comment: But i doesn't have an active subscription for that.Also i referred 
this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/00473414-4069-41e8-8f57-61a39eb82028/azure-no-subscriptions-found?forum=windowsazuremanagement.
But nothing seems to be help

Comment: Please share us with runId. We can take a quick look.

Comment: Here the run_id

16d23903-8083-4ee4-9d2b-cdc9071225f0_636299109000000000_636299118000000000_AzureOutputBlobDatasetTemplate

Comment: I saw the problem. Your region was full. We added additional subscriptions to the pool, so please try again. Choosing other region will also temporarily unblock your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Verification !
I tried with other region for my HDInsightOndemand (EastUS).Now also i'm seeing the same error.This is my run_id 
855d3b47-2b08-4218-9a01-76417bc0aa8e_636305256000000000_636305265000000000_AzureOutputBlobDatasetTemplate
I'm not understand that the region you are mentioned above is for the region for HDInsightondemand creation or the output Location ?

Comment: Sorry, I think there's another issue we're investigating... Will get back to you.

Comment: BTW, your issue is different from what we're looking. You can't create HDI in eastus, but link to storage in IndiaSouh. For best performance, they should be in the same region.

Comment: I couldn't get the point you are saying.What is the actual region to make work my ondemand  HDI? I already tried with the region SouthIndian,East US. Nothing works for me.In both cases also i tried to change my blob storage region in SouthIndian and EastUS. I couldn't get any clue for the region for this :(

Comment: Just realized that IndiaSouth is not in the list of supported regions. Here's the full supported region list.

EastUs
EastUs2
WestUs
NorthEurope
USCentral
USSouthCentral
USNorthCentral
WestEurope
SoutheastAsia
EastAsia
JapanEast
JapanWest
AustraliaEast
AustraliaSoutheast
BrazilSouth

Comment: You hit three issues, 1) a bug in ADF (just fixed); 2) IndiaSouth is not supported; 2) cluster location and storage location are not in the same region. Please try again in EastUS. Sorry for the inconvenience.